# How to read a date with ExcelBundle [Symfony Bundle]

Tags: php, excel, datetime

I'm having an issue while I'm trying to read cell value with `$cell->getCalculatedValue()` of a DateTime cell.

The excel file value is `28/2/15` (in format d/m/y) but I get `42063`.

Is this a problem with the format? If it is, how I can solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Excel date/time values are a float, not a formatted string, or any other special datatype; and it's only the number formatting mask that differentiates them from any other float

`getCalculatedValue()` will handle any formulae, but won't apply any formatting, so you'll simply get the float value back

however

`getFormattedValue()` will calculate any formula for the cell, but also apply any number formatting mask, so a "date" will be returned as a formatted string dependent on the number format mask for that cell

**EDIT**

The formatted string returned is dependent on the number format mask used.... unfortunately some MS Excel date format masks are locale aware, but PHPExcel is not, so if the cell uses one of these masks then the result may not be formatted as you'd want.

You can apply manual formatting for a cell value, using a format mask of your choice:

```
$result = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString(
    $cell->getCalculatedValue(),
    PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY
);
```

or

```
$result = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString(
    $cell->getCalculatedValue(),
    'dd/mm/yy'
);
```

Alternatively, you can convert that MS Excel serialized timestamp to a unix timestamp using

```
$result = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(
    $cell->getCalculatedValue()
);
```

or to a PHP DateTime object

```
$result = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject(
    $cell->getCalculatedValue()
);
```

and then use normal PHP `date()` or `DateTime::format()` masking to format it however you want

**EDIT #2**

To identify if a cell contains a date:

```
if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
    echo 'Cell ', $cell->getCoordinate(), ' contains a date value';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It work.
Anyway I get `02-28-15` instead of `28/02/15`. Do I need to tell to PHPExcel_Cell which format I need?

Comment: Ok, but what if I don't know if the cell content is a string, a number or a date? I have a FOR to extract all cell value of a row, and it's not all dates

Comment: See edit #2 to identify cells containing a date value